# How to backup/restore IIS 5.1 or move to another machine?

Tags: iis, backup

We have a web based application that run on an Intranet. For various reasons, we are constrained to using Win XP and the version of IIS that ships with it, 5.1.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/325889 talks about backing up IIS, but the sentence:

"This backup method does not work if you reinstall your operating system."

makes me nervous. Our main reason for backing up is in the event of catastrophic failure, which would certainly mean reinstalling the operating system. I imagine there must be a fairly painless mechanism for backing up and restoring to a fresh machine (or moving to a different one), but I have not found it. Also this is instructions for manually backing up. An automated process would be even better.

thanks!

Comment: Just for Note.  Windows XP Ships with IIS 5.2 not 5.1  The main difference between 5.2 and 5.1 is that 5.2 only allows 1 web site in the UI.

Comment: It's academic since we have only a single site, but our machines all report that they are running XP SP3, and IIS 5.1. I'm sure no one went out of their way to install a different version of IIS than was shipped.

Answer (score 1):

IIS5.x was/is an unmanageable beast.

If it is just one site, don't worry about it. Seriously - just take some good notes about how to set it up, and move on.

You've probably spent more time trying to find a good backup than you would've spent taking the notes.

However, if you must have *something*, then back up the whole machine. If there's a catastrophic failure, restore the whole machine.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The IIS Meta data backups were not ment for migration.  However you could use a Metabase Editor to get the Metadata and restore to another machine. Just remember the meta data is not the content of the website but only the configuration.  You must remember to get a copy of the Content files.

If your worried about a catastrophic failure where new server is needed I would consider a some backup software.

Comment: Thanks - I'm aware that the meta data is not the content. Backing up the content is not a problem.

I hope I am mistaken, but as far as I can tell the Metabase editors use the same process and have the same limitations as described above. They cannot be used to move a metabase to another PC or fresh installation. If you can direct me to to a tool that you know for certain does not have this limitation, I'd be grateful.